# Why not move off-topic questions instead of closing?

Tags: discussion, scope, closed-questions, migration

It seems there must be hundreds of questions closed as off-topic.

For example:
[Python - PYTHONPATH in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18247333/python-pythonpath-in-linux)

> Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

So why not just move the question so it can remain open?

Comment: Only hundreds? Lol.

Comment: As a person who is not versed in the etiquette of SO, this is indeed the reason why I rarely ask a question. There might be so many reasons to close a question. One example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25266909/where-is-the-source-code-for-the-earliest-c-compilers. I totally understand it might be against the SO policy, but it would be so awesome if there is some more liberal space on the SO network as well. This place can receive the irrelevant questions (instead of them being closed).

Answer (score 18):

Not every question deserves to remain open, here or elsewhere. We only migrate the very best questions.

Not every question has a home somewhere on the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: I still think it's pretty naïve to tell the user "You can try <other site>" and expect that they will do anything other than repost the question in its current state at that other site, defeating the migration mechanism (or the denial thereof) entirely. In fact, I think that's the point of the question: if you're going to recommend a site *anyway*, might as well migrate it, even if it's crap and we don't like migrating crap ourselves.

Comment: Alternatively, we could *not* recommend another site for crap questions..

Comment: @Blorgbeard see [Add a “don't migrate crap” migration 'path' to all sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225006/165773) at MSE

Comment: Can we leverage the wisdom of the crowd to correct for when the "experts" are wrong? Should some questions be re-opened when evidence shows people are learning from the questions?

Comment: Wow.  Nothing quite so well sums up the egalitarian toxicity SO is having such a challenge with.  Bravo.

Answer (score 11):

Not all questions are good enough to be migrated. Some of them are very badly written that they're not answerable *anywhere*. Closing them as off-topic allows you to take the best decision. If the question is good and answerable, but just not on-topic on Stack Overflow, it can be migrated to the correct site. If the question is of poor quality, there's no point in migrating to a different site as it will only cause clutter.

Comment: I think they are bringing up a different issue. What about the questions that were closed - but the community is still up-voting them? Someone is gaining value which means Stack could benefit helping them.

Answer (score 2):

This particular question is on topic for Stack Overflow.  Who more than programmers wants to know about `PythonPATH`? It could be closed as 'too broad', but not for the reason it was closed as.

Comment: It's definitely "too broad"...

Answer (score -9):

I believe in the idea *with* the caveat of a modification as we have a 133 communities in SE and in essence we could build a "Bunny Hill" community in StackExchange.

Sometimes questions are closed but it is clear some users are getting value. Upvotes on closed questions show people are clearly getting value.

I believe we can leverage the "wisdom of the crowd." The modification would be that if a closed question doesn't belong in StackOverflow and yet the crowd is showing that it is valuable via upvotes, then move the question to a new "Bunny Hill" community. That improves the quality of StackOverflow and yet still delivers the value to a new "beginner" community.

Here are some thoughts why it could be worth doing.

(1) I believe we can be guided by the "wisdom" of the crowd. Here is one CLOSED question where [35 people up voted it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17049416/what-is-the-idea-folder). Many other closed questions have up votes It appears that people gain value from closed content.

(2) Today, Stack could be discarding tapping the long tail value of questions by never reopening questions that subsequently show they are benefiting users by their up votes. Long tails can be the source of untapped value. Amazon built a business out of the long tail. Perhaps Stack can imagine something to do.

(3) Most elite ski resorts in the world built bunny hills. Maybe there is something to learn from that.

(4) All of us, even if experts in one area, are newbies in another. The number of newbies is a far larger population than the experts. We could quantify the viability of a "reopened" question community by counting how many closed questions have significant up votes.

(5) Tapping the long prevents StackOverflow from suffering from classic Clayton Christiansen disruption up from the bottom. Stack can prevent disruption by removing the risk that other sites thrive by addressing a lower end-of-the-market. Stack can seed its future too much like Google seeds the lower end of the market, like schools, with free software. Stack can serve beginning programmers as opposed to losing them.

(6) Serving beginning developers is charitable. We were all beginners once.

How could it be done? Leave the system exactly like it is now. The community closes question. But if a question gets X number of up votes, then automatically move it to the Stack "Bunny Overflow" community, and re-open it. Stack then gets the wisdom of the "beginner" crowd to curate the best content. Disruption averted. Long tail tapped. Stack wins.

Comment: "We lose BEGINNING PROGRAMMERS" - That would be _so incredibly awesome_! Most of them hardly know how to format a post, never mind asking a coherent, on-topic question. Sadly it's not going to happen as they're just going to keep on asking low quality questions and creating new accounts once they're questionbanned.

Comment: You may wish to read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254381/should-we-fork-stack-overflow-for-beginning-programmers and the associated dups.

Comment: Of course they will keep answering "low quality" questions. One man's trash is another man's treasure.

Comment: Also, you keep mentioning "business" way too often. That's where your "ski resort" analogy falls flat: a ski resort wants to make money. And while SE inc. certainly wants to make money as well, this is clearly not the primary interest of the SE _community_. E.g. I would _love_ a site to pop up that "addresses a lower end of the market" which would siphon the noobs off of SO and reduce the volume of LQ questions.

Comment: The ski resort metaphor still fits unless I am misunderstanding your point. SE serves multiple roles. The ideas the original poster suggests fulfills each: (1) it siphons off noobs to a new site; (2) it meets new business opportunities for SE; (3) it serves SE other roles which is cultivating an educated developer base; (4) it helps SE mitigate the negativity experienced by noobs; (5) it is "philanthropic" and "socially responsible."

Comment: The other site of questions is yahoo answers. The quality there is poor. Also realize that up votes and close votes are orthogonal. One measures popularity, the other the topically on the site. Not all questions are good ones for the Q&A format.

Comment: Yes MichaelT - they are orthogonal. I believe that following that logic the  conclusion would be that if a Q&A is popular as measured by upvotes, but closed as not belonging on Stack, then move it. It doesn't belong here. BUT because there is value to be harvested, one solution is to move the question to a new community where it belongs.  There are 133 communities today in SE. I believe that a "Bunny Hill" community auto-populated with the Q&As that we don't want on StackOverflow is one simple solution to harvesting that value.

Comment: Grab a data dump of the site. Find all the closed questions. Dump them into a stack clone. Follow proper attribution and have them be reopened.  However, you should check the quality of the questions first... Just to get an idea of what you are suggesting. Most closed questions are, quite frankly, either crap or don't fit into the Q&A format. But you should look at that for yourself first to see if it's true or not.