# Stack Overflow Basics, tutorial style minisite

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Sometimes, particularly when reviewing first posts, you'll often see very basic questions that could be solved with a bit of Googling. This generally isn't the sort of question that Stack Overflow should be addressing, and they usually don't show much research work.

However, when I'm trying to learn how to do something, I'll look for a Stack Overflow link in preference to almost any other site. This means that I'll usually have to find someone who's attempted and failed to do what I'm trying to do, and then got a solution, rather than just flat out finding a tutorial.

This seems counter-intuitive, but the reason I do it is the Stack Overflow experience is so much nicer than pretty much any other site. Most of the programming sites are hideously designed and it gives me brain ache trying to find where the tutorial is, and others like the Microsoft tutorials site whilst they look nice, are so determined to cover off every eventuality that you have to sift through a lot of content to interpret the actual solution.

What I'm proposing then is a Stack Overflow Basics minisite that preemptively gives concise, SO style answers the sort of beginner, nuts and bolts tutorials that you find on other sites but that are a pain to go through; basically a beginners tutorial section that users can contribute to as and when they feeling generous.

Thoughts?

Comment: Beginner questions *are* answered, but find the duplicate before asking, since it is already there. A thousand times.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A site. Tutorials are not Q&A.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - What I'm proposing is slightly different, as it wouldn't lock anybody off. I'm suggesting a body of basic questions for beginners to learn from, not a reputation based system (though there will inevitably be some crossover.)

Comment: @Substantial No, but what I'm suggesting is a slightly different tact to the current site. Tutorials can be in a Q&A format, anyway - e.g. Q: How do I assign a value from a query to a variable in Access? A: Use Dlookup, and so on.

Comment: @BFDatabaseAdmin, I realize that, but I opted to select the "canonical" duplicate for requests of this kind. If you look in the linked questions list in the duplicate, you will find proposal closer to yours, such as [Should we fork Stack Overflow for beginning programmers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254381/464709)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - Fair enough. Why do you think these sort of suggestions get downvoted so quickly? The amount of duplicate suggestions (nothing came up when I was searching to see if someone had already suggested it, perhaps because I was using different terminology, but sorry for the dupe) would suggest that there's an appetite for it somewhere?

Comment: Also, while these suggestions end up heavily downvoted, there's usually a significant minority of up-voters as well - it's usually split 2:1 (as is, currently, this question).

Comment: @BFDatabaseAdmin, this feature request is quite common indeed. However, the community's consensus so far is that it's a bad idea, and downvotes may very well come quickly because of a "That feature request? *Again?* Oh well" reaction.

Comment: We could call it **"Stack Undertow"**.

Answer (score 3):

A more comment*ish* answer

Just because they are basic questions doesn't mean they shouldn't be answered. If the OP delivers a nicely formatted question, that was not asked before, shows research and understanding as to where the problem is but OP's knowledge is not enough to solve it then it deserves an answer.. or it will be marked as a duplicate... in which case he'll get the answer with some down-votes

Most of the problems with beginners is that they don't know how to search or find what they want and from what I learned SO was not made to do that for them.

What I would suggest for beginners it to read the *Tag info*

Here a few examples

- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info
- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info
- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info
- https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c++/info

It has nice resources like links to SO questions and tutorials, books, small code scripts and more..

I also like what [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) does to make it simple in searching the questions that were asked a lot of times. This is also a good read for people who want to know more about the language since some of them are basic questions about how it works or what it does.

So I would suggest not to create a separate place for beginners since SO already has most of the resources a beginner needs while still staying Q&A

Comment: I can confirm this answer is right. My first question was a very simple beginner question- And it's my highest voted question so far. Actually, I think you're even the one that answered it. So double proof we don't need a separate site.