# Stack Overflow fatigue - has your usage / motivation dropped off?

Tags: discussion

I joined Stack Overflow during the private beta testing phase - I had the time of my life posting answers, asking questions, learning by reading other's questions. That was 2009.

Over the last few years, I've contributed less and less - can't even call myself a lurker now. Some of it can be attributed to having less time as I progress into mid-life. However, we make time for things that we care about...

- My occasional visits to Stack Overflow inundate me with a lot of noise/beginner/low quality questions... I hardly find a question that I learn something from any link on the first page. I tried filtering down to [RSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) on tags - even then the noise is too much.
- My questions get buried pretty soon - they don't get the adequate screen time I guess. My recent questions do not get 3+ answers - accepted answers are getting rare.
- Stack Overflow has grown enormously: It WAS a close community. The average post quality
  and user expertise was outstanding. Has it suffered a scaling problem?

Anyone else suffering from this? I 'want' to use Stack Overflow, but lately it's been hard - I am trying to figure out what has changed.

Note: Not trying to start a flame war here - constructive discussion is the goal here.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296166/17034

Comment: @HansPassant - Jeff left?!! I've really been out of the loop. Great post!

Comment: I'm saddened but happy for Jeff n https://twitter.com/theladybabies

Comment: @HansPassant I still don't understand how "Spolsky was right and Atwood was wrong".

Comment: I don't either.  You'll have to ask the tens of thousands of SO users that wouldn't have posted a question if that would not have happened.  Afaik Spolsky has to keep the investors happy, they throw money at SE to keep their untrained low-wage employees productive.  Bottom-line stuff.

Comment: @HansPassant Ah. I had hoped that Spolsky was a developer before a businessman, but clearly it's the other way around. And as anyone who's worked in a situation where business is prioritised over dev can tell you - the end result is always, always a big ball of s**t.

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm new to being an active participant, but I'm not demotivated by the reasons you cite.  Those problems do certainly exist, but I don't find it that hard to find something productive to do.  I can still find questions of decent quality, or fight the (admittedly large) fires via review queues.  The meta community is fairly close-knit.  Maybe it's just easier to stand on a soapbox, but I've gotten great feedback from all my meta posts.

Comment: Simple advice - find a new technology, learn it and start answering questions. The community is really bad on older technologies, e.g. Java. It's much better on newer languages and frameworks.

Comment: I find it really frustrating that the most simple answers (to beginner questions) are the best way to get reputation by far. Spend some time and effort to answer a more difficult question, get, maybe, an upvote and accept, if you're lucky. But, the quickest answer that instead of `std::strign` OP should use `std::string` and BAM 5 upvotes in the bag. (Yes, a slight hyperbole) It's really hard to find interesting questions to answer.

Comment: There is more than one way to contribute. You could instead represent the average user of Stack Overflow (90% is read-only, hits from Google): When you use Stack Overflow as a research tool (say, when moving into a new area like [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell)) improve the top search hits you get: finding duplicates, writing a comprehensive answer if none exists, editing, and commenting ([sometimes it works](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15192/installing-raspbian-from-noobs-without-display/19928#19928) (different site, though)).

Comment: You are finding less interesting questions and less questions to learn from because **you** have learned more. **You** have become a better programmer as you gained more experience, so the questions that used to excite you are now boring because you don't learn from them anymore. The questions you ask don't get viewed/answered as often because they're of higher difficulty than the average user is capable of. Yes, the community got bigger, but that's not the only cause of experienced users losing interest.

Comment: Yes, answering questions is pretty demotivating on several counts: 1) No upvotes for decent answers, mainly when you deal with new users, 2) Many many many duplicates which are claimed as **No my question is not the duplicate you indicate** (I guess since it is not really literally their answer while you already know it is a duplicate). I think a new function in which the higher rated users are allowed to remove questions quicker with just a **duplicate, google better, learn to code yourself, or come back when you read the manual** remark from a single user, might be a really beneficial idea.

Comment: I swear if Hans Passant only ran for president.  Everything he said in the comments and on his post is so true.  Spolsky ruined this place ages ago.

Comment: If negative votes didn't exists, this would be a great achievement. i once suffered of it, claimed to not have been altered, but in fact it reduced drastically my interest to propose solutions. the 'don't take it personaly' is just a not possible.

Comment: Dropped off?  No.  More like killed by too many people playing FGITW, and too many people on meta defending FGITW.  Although yes, the rate at which new questions get buried (and/or flooded with quick, low-quality answers from everyone vying to be first) hasn't helped either.

Comment: @KevinB so true! +1. There was a time, I was scared about joining the elite named SO-Community.

Comment: I find it ironic that people write questions about low quality posts (or related issues) on Stack Overflow that don't indicate any searching of Meta Stack Overflow for previous questions related to the topic they're writing about.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm - That's a design problem, not a user problem.  If users are meant to research before posting, then it's the platform's job to do that automatically for them while they're posting (and more accurately/thoroughly than what it currently does, which often misses relevant things and/or returns irrelevant things).  It's not the user's job to do that manually.  You might ask it of them, but in that case the only irony is in knowledgeable software developers believing that users will do anything more than the UI strictly requires, and expressing disappointment when they don't.

Comment: Just one data point: I don't know how many of you remember me being extremely active > 2 years ago, but if you did, you might have noticed that I've been mostly just lurking on the site since, posting fewer questions and answers. Usually the answers I *do* post get downvoted because I tend to give succinct and to-the-point answers and people think anything short of an essay or anything without a ton warnings about some bad practice must be bad quality. So yes, my motivation has dropped off too. Good to know I'm not the only one.

Comment: @AndrewGrimm - if that poke was meant for me, I did watch the related questions pane and didn't find any while composing. . If the community is so hung-up on prevent dupes n low quality questions, maybe you should moderate incoming questions ; nip them in the bud. I did search this time on meta... n found nothing. #PitOfSuccess

Comment: Perhaps relevant: [the 3 types of SO users, and the apathic](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/2821954)

Answer (score 139):

Imagine this process:

1. I click a question whose title intrigues me.
2. Then:

   - The question is clear, or at least clear-ish, and I start searching for duplicates, continue at #4, OR
   - I read the question, and (through experience) **know** information is missing.
3. I start typing a comment explaining what information is missing, and whether OP wants to [edit] their question to include that. Note that I do recognize when I'm wrong, and then I admit that and remove my comments. Couple of outcomes when I'm right:

   1. OP disagrees and thinks their question is fine (or doesn't come back at all), so I downvote and close as Unclear/Incomplete. *If* I remember to check back after a while.
   2. OP agrees but doesn't know how to obtain the additional information. I go down the rabbit hole of endless comment chains, more often than not solving the problem in comments.
   3. Other people add irrelevant comments, confusing OP, who successively forgets to respond to my comments.
   4. Other people start discussing with me or OP that the question is fine.

In the meantime:

4. Answers get posted, often just guessing at the problem and copy-pasting an answer from elsewhere on the site or from their own source repository. [Often accompanied with "Try this" as only explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298811/2661430).
5. I start commenting on answers why they aren't helpful, or why their approach is wrong altogether, harmful (oh, how often copy-pasted code contains SQL injection vulnerabilities), or not relevant at all to the problem.
6. If I even *dare* to downvote an answer, even after commenting as explained in #5, it is almost always immediately countered back to 0, yielding the answerer a positive reputation change, so they won't remove it.
7. OP accepts one of the answers, and I'm the jerk in the room because *"The answer helped OP"*. Yeah, helped as in "set on fire":

   > Build a man a fire, and he'll be warm for a day. Set a man on fire, and he'll be warm for the rest of his life.

This process takes at least five minutes.

After an encounter or three of this, I'm tired of it, and just answer the next question that I happen to open - even though it's a duplicate or unclear (but where I *can* properly guess the problem). This takes a minute or two, zero effort, no frustration and usually gives me 1-5 upvotes.

What do you want me to be, a good citizen that cares for quality, or a content generating machine?

So yeah, that is sometimes harming my motivation a bit.

Comment: Also a very recognizable answer. Those 5 wasted minutes where everything that can be done wrong is done wrong add 30 minutes of mental tiredness to your day, at least.

Comment: You're giving too much emotional weight to the downvoting and what-their-vote-ends-up-being. A critical comment, especially from an experienced user like yourself, is quite damning for people taking the site seriously. That is, assuming it's not derivise. Anyway, we (lower-rep users) do appreciate your efforts very much! A winner is you!

Comment: You can save a lot of effort (for everyone involved, not just yourself) by downvoting and close-voting immediately, instead of typing a comment and *maybe* circling back later. In the process you describe, if you forget to come back, one more user with close vote privileges has to waste their time reading the question and voting on it; sometimes this even makes the difference between the question being closed and left open. If you're feeling charitable, leaving a comment is great, but there's already an explanation in the close dialog.

Comment: If you "**know** information is missing" (in bold!), I'd say that's pretty obviously closeworthy. Good point about the dupehammer, though...I don't have one, so it makes little difference for me.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: It's obvious to the one voting to close, but not to other readers, is what CodeCaster is saying.

Comment: "OP disagrees and thinks their question is fine (or doesn't come back at all), so I downvote and close as Unclear/Incomplete. If I remember to check back after a while." epic fail here: [you should first vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/221880/213575), *then* comment. Also, maybe no comment at all. For [Shog it worked](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265769/), for me too (or at very least, I don't find the same crap floating after I voted).

Comment: Ahh... This all sounds too familiar. I can't remember when I last upvoted *anything* on this site. And usually this whole mess take much longer than 5 minutes. Sometimes you spend an hour trying to help while OP eventually accepted some VLQ "Try this" answer.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, many old post are certainly deserve upvotes. Many of them were posted when new technology appeared; they have already got upvotes from those who learn that technology. and when such Q&A help me to solve my issue, I'm more than happy to upvote them both!

Comment: The flip side of this is also true. The higher the noise, the less likely [interesting and difficult questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33857632/1048539) are to be noticed and answered (yes I'm biased). So many of the users who might otherwise have the good questions observe their hard and good questions don't get answered, so they stop posting. That's been my experience, at least...

Answer (score 53):

I feel the same way (had a former account much older than this one, but it was tied to an account from a former workplace I was at).

To me it's just the sheer scale of the community now. I had similar experiences when I was young and playing online games -- they'd have an awesome community full of people that really care about things and then, years later, the game turns into this epic thing with millions of users and now it turns into like a grind where everyone wants the best gear and asking for free items or something like that.

Communities have a tendency to degrade that way with scale.

After seeing the 10,000th kind of "please do my homework for me" question or "what's the best software to do this?" or "can someone recommend a book?" kind of question, it starts to get tiring.

Quality questions that are challenging and interesting to think about are getting sparse, and on some days it feels miserable where not a single new question in a tag is outside of the above category of questions.

I start doing some things which I probably shouldn't, which is to answer some of those bad questions out of sheer boredom (because they're the only ones around).

I'm personally addicted to questions which are a bit challenging to answer, require a bit of work and thought. That or questions which just address a pet peeve of mine -- some common misconception in the programming world. I typically don't have too many questions of my own, but I find the process of trying to answer them to be educational itself. So it becomes really dull when all I find in a day are those kinds of basic lazy questions.

Maybe another woe independent of SO but just the world at large is that I'm primarily a desktop programmer working in low-level systems in languages like C and C++, the occassional assembly, with an interest in data-oriented design. The world has shifted a lot to web-related work, mobile, etc. -- which are exploding in popularity. So that seems to leave a lot of questions in the areas I'm interested in of an academic breed (a lot of "please do my homework, I need to turn this in tomorrow!" kind of types). Maybe it's just an inevitability.

Comment: I hear you. My (unfounded?) concern being what if the good folks ride off into the SO sunset ? And it's not related to a specific area, my android questions have drawn blanks - even though it's a very healthy branch. I think it's the 'I can answer 5 easy questions in the time I take to research a tough one' thing.

Comment: I really think the problem lies almost solely in the questions. If the questions consist of those basic kind of lazy types, then the community evolves towards a troubleshooting type and the challenging ones get a tumbleweed response. If the questions are very interesting, challenging, professional kinds of questions, then the community evolves to favor those epic types like Mystical (one of my personal heroes since I've learned so much from the precision of his answers) -- albeit perhaps a bit intimidating for the novice. It's hard to have it both ways, but the world at large wants...

Comment: ... troubleshooting more than some of the most educational questions and answers.

Comment: @Gishu I think you just absolutely hit the nail on the head with `I think it's the 'I can answer 5 easy questions in the time I take to research a tough one'`

Comment: Sometimes I wonder if we're looking at this somewhat with nostalgia glasses (still properly, however). My memory is a little fuzzy when I first used SO when it was quite a new site, but I still remember a fair share of lazy questions. The bigger difference, I think, is that I'm seeing an increased *rarity* of more advanced, professional-breed questions. Maybe it's not so much that there are so many poor questions lately so much as the lack of good questions -- the expert types often seem to have lost interest in participating, but it's the experts that lured me to the site in the first place.

Comment: I like the gaming scale analogy, quite recognizable. Forget about the standard homework stuff: where I lose it is in the growing number of people that actively refuse to add more details to their question and just retort with "I don't believe that's relevant". Jeepers creepers.

Comment: See also: ["A Group is its Own Worst Enemy"](http://shirky.com/writings/group_enemy.html)

Comment: What is sad is that SO was specifically intended and designed to avoid just the problems of scale that you describe. But what has happened is that the means for coping with scale have been eroded (removing close reasons for crap questions because they were "being misused") and new features introduced that subvert rather than help QA (the sick joke that is Triage).

Answer (score 53):

My use of SO has decreased dramatically since the signal-to-noise ratio went through the <s>roof</s> floor. A lot of that is down to the [fastest gun in the west problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem), because when I answer I generally try to to be as verbose and explanatory as possible, which generally means my answer ends up getting posted after someone else's (often poor) answer, which means I lose out on that green checkmark. Essentially, I don't bother answering anymore.

What I have been doing is a lot more reviews, but at the end of the day those don't give rep points and they're pretty soul-destroying, so I'm now at the point where I don't care about reviews anymore either.

(For those wondering, the only reason I'm interested in rep is so I can get to 10k and thus be able to see deleted questions. I don't want rep for the sake of it.)

So Stack Overflow has essentially ceased to be a useful resource for me. Yes I still ask questions, yes I still prefer SO links when I'm Googling for a problem... but my motivation to involve myself is mostly gone.

Unfortunately, the overall tone of SO has changed from a site for **professional and enthusiast programmers** to a site where anything goes. So the only thing that made it different to every other forum, the only thing that made it better than Experts Exchange, is no longer there. Similarly, my desire - and the desire of many other high-rep users - to contribute is also no longer there.

I think we need to face up to the fact that Stack Overflow is, if not dead, very much on life support. It's been in a coma for a while, but most of the stalwarts haven't realised how far gone it is. At this point, I don't think there's anything we can do to save it, apart from segregating the swine from the pearls, and that won't be done because it's not politically correct to do so.

[Congratulations, Spolsky. You've won.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296166/17034)

But at what cost?

Comment: I've dodged the FGitW problem by concentrating on more specialized tags. e.g. [tag:requirejs] rather than [tag:javascript]. It partially takes care of that problem. I don't have a solution for the rest though, short of actually optimizing for pearls, which is what SO is no longer doing.

Comment: *"when I answer I generally try to to be as verbose and explanatory as possible"* - Unrelated to the FGitW problem, that's not always the best approach. Sometimes brevity can be much easier to follow.

Comment: @Ian, that's nitpicking, but didn't the signal-to-noise ratio go through the *floor*, not the roof? There sure is a lot of noise nowadays.

Comment: I still think this fastest gun issue is ultimately a question-related one. I can't imagine one of `Mystical's` epic posts being outgunned by an answer provided 3 minutes after the question was raised. To me the sheer traffic of questions makes it so there's no longer much incentive for questions to kind of be revisited, for those quality answers to even be worth bothering. It only becomes a speed competition when quality ceases to count. Quality questions produce quality answers.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I always find it interesting when radio metaphors are used with programming (or other areas). "Impedance mismatch" is just a silly way to talk about database integration. Most people who use these terms have no concept of their actual use, so it is an analogy for an analogy.

Comment: Psst! I think you mean the signal-to-noise ratio has *dropped*... A high S/N ratio is generally something to strive for.

Comment: Much like @Louis I've stopped tracking any high volume tags, such as `java` and `groovy` in favor of the smaller, higher quality tags like `haskell`.

Answer (score 25):

I want to argue a counter point:

- There actually isn't a larger percentage of crap than a year ago, or a year before - every year people come up and complain about how much crap there is. If anything I feel like quality is generally rising.
- There *is* more crap because there is more stuff - but if you look at specific tags that's generally not the trend.

Burnout is natural, and it makes sense that as people get tired of answering questions new people kick in and take their place.

I'm sorry you don't use the site as much - but there are people who make up for it. Answering questions in Stack Overflow is a very wearing process. There are a few trends that are different now:

- It's very hard to have a pleasant experience answering *easy* questions. When you answer a regex question or a basic question about a standard API - chances are someone will beat you to it - that's fine.
- People answer bad questions - often, this is not because they're bad people. I'd argue it's because a lot of people *want to contribute*, but don't understand the system well enough or know a specialized enough stack.

So, if you're an "advanced" user and want to contribute my tips are:

- Stick to smaller tags, as other answers suggest these tend to have a higher quality. Unless you feel like dealing with endless streams of bad questions - this is essential.
- Stick to questions that are not new. I usually filter questions that are in a subject I know and have a positive vote count and no answers. These tend to be interesting (although they also tend to not be 100+ votes questions since the problem domain is a lot smaller).
- Make canonical Q&As on new topics in programming languages. Those tend to help a lot of people, be generally useful and of high quality. They also land a lot of reputation points if you care about that.

Of course, the rules for "getting lots of reputation points" are completely different. I assume if you're reading this that's not your goal though.

Comment: very reasonable and positive angle of view! this is at least one of the ways to contribute *and* get reputation *and* improve one skills *and* have fun without stress from crap

Comment: I have to disagree on the percentages. I mean before we had the site with much lower traffic yet you had the *world record holder* of computing `pi` answering a question about computing `pi`. It might vary by tags but I don't see this anymore. If the high/low quality ratio was the same, I should be finding all kinds of questions where you now have Linus Torvalds answering a question about the linux kernel, John Carmack answering a question about computer graphics, etc. The expert answers actually seem to be getting fewer in number, while the basic beginner question are increasing.

Comment: Assuming the site has 10 times the traffic now from before, I should be seeing 10 times the number of ultra high-quality answers like this from some of the top names in the industry with such expertise that they can cite themselves as the ultimate authority. Instead I'm hard-pressed to find a single example of this over the recent year or so -- all such magnificent examples of SO at its finest are old examples from big names in the industry who no longer participate very much.

Answer (score 16):

Mine hasn't.

It is important sometimes to reflect on the path we took to get here, zoom out a little bit or risk not being able to see the forest for the trees.

*what makes Stack Overflow hard to use for a high reputation user*

For the most part, every time a user posts an answer they remember that scenario. The first answer ever posted to Stack Overflow is almost guaranteed to be a fresh scenario encountered. As a result, the ratio of encountered scenarios per answer decreases with each answer posted. This ratio increases friction in answering, as there are qualms with continually solving the same problem - fatigue, as noted; balking, such as trying to decide what proper tool to use (duplicate closure, commenting, creating canonical posts, etc.); boredom, a sense that progress isn't being made.

*relation of learning versus time*

Part of posting answers to more and more unique questions is learning. Almost every new situation increases some aspect of awareness with that topic. This can be exciting when certain questions raise problems that are truly fascinating to solve. However, as time progresses so does the level of awareness with these problems and the result is that the fascination doesn't occur as often.

*complexity of posts over time*

While each post answered or addressed increases awareness of nuance and the level of overall education in that subject, it also increases the level of complexity included in each post authored. This has the direct result of making answers very informative and helpful to others, but also making questions posed very hard to grasp and formulate a solution to from others as well.

*amount of users total versus users who understand a given complexity*

87% of the Stack Overflow user base is below 200 reputation. The reason that complex questions posed do not receive attention is because they sadly do not apply to the broader user base here at Stack Overflow. For example, only 12% of users at Stack Overflow have more than 200 reputation. If the question requires an expert in the topic, chances are they probably (there is not a direct correlation between expertise and reputation, but there is still a correlation) will have more than 200 reputation. Using the same metric, getting an answer from a 1000+ reputation user would only be possible from 4% of the user base here.

*janitorial tools*

If all you go looking for is trash, that is all you will ever find. This has been true for a very long time on Stack Overflow. Attempting to filter out quality material from the front page while sifting through all of the other material there has been equated to "drinking from a firehose." Having more and more access to moderation tools just makes it easier to look for trash on the site, and it can be easy to get lost in doing that.

*this isn't new*

However, given all of these points, none of this is a particularly new problem at Stack Overflow. It is understandable that certain aspects discussed may lead to discouragement but there are reasons for reaching that point. Years of education in the form of solving fascinating problems, years of helping other users understand complex solutions to what appear to be simple problems, and years of helping to keep trash off of the site. The main aspect here is just outlook.

*users are not malicious*

The more complexity you are comfortable with, the longer it can take to find it. As noted, 87% of users are under 200 reputation and are probably still at the beginning of the learning curve. Watching every new question means that more than likely 9/10 are about learning (perhaps even about something simple). However, this doesn't mean that users trying to learn - even about simple topics - are problematic. They certainly didn't set out to offend someone looking for complex problems, they set out to solve a problem they are having trouble learning about.

*what type of learning do new users do*

New users come to Stack Overflow excited. Their ratio of finding fascinating solutions is very high. This leads to an expectation that each problem encountered will lead to a fascinating explanation and as a result every time a problem is faced they run to post it eagerly awaiting what should surely be new to everyone. It is common for all people to project their situation to the broader population - everyone does this, even me. However, this doesn't always work out so well when the assumption about the solution being new fails to pan out.

*tolerance*

When you see someone who fails to make a proper assumption about a solution being applicable to the broader population, don't let it increase your fatigue. Instead, use it to remember all of the times you were fascinated by a topic here on Stack Overflow and keep in mind that was the intention of that user's post. This isn't to say that the post cannot be actioned when appropriate (downvote,vtc, etc.) - it is to say that it should not bring you down. It is just someone excited to learn, and now there are nearly 5 million of them.

Comment: This sort of describes my current stance and participation on SO as well. I can't help noticing 87%+12% = 99%. Is "Jon Skeet is a whole percentile category by himself" the reason?

Comment: @Jongware - I truncated :) Re: Jon Skeet, what I find inspiring from him is that he always manages to find good questions to answer. When I have trouble finding something interesting to answer, I will find myself thinking "Jon Skeet is finding good questions."

Comment: Jon Skeet also finds a lot of crap questions and answers them instead of looking for a duplicate to close it.

Comment: @ThomasWeller: I do *try* not to do that (and I cast *plenty* of dupe flags) - but inevitably there are some that I'll answer and then others will find a dupe, or where I consider it not a dupe and others think it *is* a dupe. I will say that I find considerably fewer good questions to answer than I used to. (Look at my answer rates now and a few years ago, and you'll see a marked difference.)

Answer (score 14):

No, I don't think my motivation or interest has dropped off. Perhaps that's because I spend my time answering questions in less popular tags such as [oracle] or [plsql]. Are there a lot of crap questions? Sure. And there are going to be until such time as SO implements an SO-Professional-Or-Enthusiast-Programmer-Certification process, which I'm guessing ain't gonna happen - and would probably kill the site if it did.

But let's imagine, for a moment, that such a system was put in place - you had to pass an official test before you were qualified to ask (let alone *answer*) questions on SO. You'd get your Official SO Badge (but with no pin on it - you can't trust us programmer-geeks to handle sharp objects without poking our own eyes out! Think of the liability issues..! :-), you'd get your Official SO Decoder Ring (which, because it only implements DES, is really not all *that* secure...), you'd be taught the Secret SO Handshake, the SO Alma Mater, and the SO Fight Song - oh, it'd be a frabjous day, no doubt.

And then what?

Well, the What I think would happen Then is...*crickets*. The wind howling lonely across the barren tundra of StackOverflow. Emptiness. Nothingness. The absence of Being. Put a dead, gnarled tree out there on the horizon, maybe with a couple of strategically placed buzzards, and you'd have yourself a pretty good-looking Desolation. Why is this, you ask? Let's say that as Certified-SO-Professionals-and-Enthusiasts you (and I say "you" because I'm not certain I could qualify. Despite having spent over 40 years as a programmer I become more painfully aware with each passing year of how little I know vis-a-vis how much there is to know. Sad, ain't it?) are 100% efficient at weeding out duplicates and ask only well-thought-out and original questions. Pretty soon we're gonna run out of well-thought-out, original questions and...*crickets*. Every once in a while some new explorer, a freshly-minted SO Badge in hand, might venture in, stop to view the Desolation, and move on to somewhere more...lively. More...active. More...useful. Someplace more like a corner bar than an ivory tower. (Ivory towers are all very nice, but frankly they tend to be cold, drafty, and you can't usually get a decent beer or bad chili :-). Are all the duplicates and crappy questions annoying? No, not really, unless you give them more value than I think they're worth. It costs me nothing to blip past them - give a quick read then either Ignore, Close, or whatever. But as [someone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturgeon%27s_law) once said, "90% of everything is crap". This applies to SO postings as well - and would probably still apply even if all the questions were posting by Certified SO Professionals and all the duplicates and crap questions were weeded out - because then many of what are currently seen as "good" questions would be re-labeled as "crap" and the cycle would continue - perhaps until only One Single Shining True-And-Perfect SO Question was left - at which point 90% of it would be edited out as "extraneous, irrelevant, immaterial, inaccurate, or obsolete". At which point the cycle would repeat itself...

Pax.

Comment: This answer reminds me of Tony the Pony for some reason.

Comment: Z͇̞̽ͯ̏̏̌͠͝A̪̟̪̲̼̫̜ͧ̒L̳̻͕̣͎̅̓̇̆͗ͮ͝G̀̌̐̈ͮ҉̱̻̜̹̖̼̗Õ̡̩̺̞̣̩̦̖̳͙͗̊̄̐̉̕!̧̭̹̖̠̖͈̦ͩ̓͗̃ͪ̌͟                :-)

Comment: this kind of assumes that the 'intermediate+' users know everything and hence wouldn't post questions - thereby the 'barren wasteland' scenario. I disagree - I have lots of questions. The only thing I'm asking for is for a bit of moderation for incoming questions I guess.

Answer (score 11):

My motivation to use SO hasn't dropped (it may have even increased,) however, the things I enjoy doing on the site have changed drastically. I used to really enjoy answering questions and helping people learn how to debug, but as I became better and better at it, it became less and less of a challenge, and I began getting less and less out of answering questions. Even reputation-wise there's no drive to gain more reputation because 1. I don't gain anything for it, and 2. 100k seems too far away to push for (I'd love some SO swag.) Now, I spend the majority of my time here moderating, attempting to help users improve their questions, and participating in Meta SO.

My original motivation for using Stackoverflow was to gain experience in quickly and efficiently solving problems, but now I'm at a point where I feel like I'm not gaining anything more from answering questions, so I've moved more in the direction of helping others get to that point.

Comment: So you moved on from helping people *directly* to helping them *indirectly*! And the site, as a whole, benefits from this - not just the people you point to the Help Center to help them make their questions better.

Comment: My goal is to get askers to become answerers. Once that transition happens, it's usually a followed by a period of.... enlightenment for lack of a better term where the user goes through answering questions and getting better and better at what they do. I want to get developers out of that phase where they can't figure it out on their own. Once you get out of that (which takes a lot of confidence in your own abilities,) things really take off.

Comment: To my mind, the biggest thing SO needs to do now is find a good way to award rep for moderation actions, like closing duplicate questions and improving questions and answers. The site is at the stage (in some tags, at least) where that's what's most needed. Good moderation is of tremendous value, and yet the mechanism by which SO indicates what's valuable (rep) doesn't reflect that.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not a Stack Overflow veteran, but a beginner, however I've learned a lot by reading other people's answers. My usage on the site hasn't dropped; instead it has increased (to solve most of my questions), however my motivation *has* dropped: I find that sometimes I answer an OP's question in the comments and someone copy-pastes my comment (Yeah, they don't even change a letter!), it gets about 3-5 upvotes which might have been mine if I have had the courage to post an **answer** instead of a **comment**!

I find myself being frustrated with it, but also by finding that as a beginner (I mean at programming related topics), because I'm still a student and a worker, it's hard for me to answer highly technical questions and get reputation by doing so, so I need to concentrate on low level / quality posts which sometimes require a lot of effort to get 1-2 upvotes if any and maybe if OP decides to come back and accept an answer...

I agree with @CodeCaster that my questions / answers don't stand in a place for a decent amount of time so it makes it harder for us (relatively new users) to get reputation or recognition or maybe a comment from other user who can help me to improve my code for performance or something similar. It makes me not want to answer questions sometimes...

Comment: @Peter Mortensen thanks for edit! I appreciate that (I also learn from this)

Comment: Don't get frustrated - get motivated! There's no shame in deleting an answer that proves unnecessary, especially if by overcoming your fear you're able to post more answers that are useful instead of leaving them in comments for others to salvage...

Comment: Taking an answer that was posted in the comments and reposting it where it belongs is actually the right thing to do, although they should be mentioning you.

Comment: @Shog9 yeah I'll take that in mind next time, I'll add answers when apply and if they don't, well... just delete them... :) And you're right Josh they should but they don't, however I won't give up C:

Answer (score 7):

Personally, in addition to some of the other people's reasons, I have the extra reason that the gamification of Stack Overflow has worn off for me.

I mean look:

- I have 185k reputation...
- I have almost every badge (just missing some esoteric badges like Unsung Hero, or nigh-impossible ones like Publicist)...
- I have the gold badge in every tag I frequent (including [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) when 90% of the time my answers consist of "don't use jQuery")
- I have stickers and at least one mug for being so active

What else is there for me to achieve?

So yeah. In addition to the reasons given in earlier answers, I would add that many of the things that kind of drove me to participate have run dry. Game over.

Comment: Me too (and I have almost twice your rep in the same set of tags!). Personally, I stick around not because I'm masochistic and enjoy dealing with crap (being a mod isn't all unicorns and rainbows) - but because every now and then [something comes along that I find interesting and consider myself in a good position to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/users/106224/boltclock?tab=answers&sort=newest). The gamification wore off on me a *long* time ago. I don't need gamification to continue answering genuinely interesting questions, but I contribute far less often now than I used to. And that's OK.

Comment: I'm slowly creeping toward 4k on the "interest" of my previous contributions, but I already feel this way.  What's left to earn, another set of votes to feel bad about not completely using every day?

Answer (score 4):

> The average post quality and user expertise was outstanding. Has it suffered a scaling problem?

Yes. A friend of mine categorizes this as a basic "law of averages" problem. He and I used to work in a software company that, when we started, was fairly small. All employees were above average, most were *well* above average. But as the company grew, it became impossible to retain this level of quality. The law of averages caught up with the company, and the population in the company began to more closely reflect that of the rest of the world.

The same thing is happening (has happened) to Stack Overflow. I see it most clearly in searches for questions so trivial, they probably shouldn't even be here. I do the searching so that I can close as "duplicate" new questions that are similarly so trivial that they shouldn't have been asked. I perform the search using the Stack Overflow search feature, sort by "Newest", and skip to the end to walk backwards looking for the oldest relevant duplicate.

Invariably, the oldest posts are *not* the duplicates I'm looking for. They were posted to Stack Overflow in its early years, by people who didn't need a site like Stack Overflow to find answers to such trivial questions. To find the relevant duplicate, I usually need to get at least into 2010 or so.

On the other hand, it is not clear to me that such Q&A's were ever intended to not be part of Stack Overflow. Just that they didn't appear in the early days, due to the makeup of the community.

> Anyone else suffering from this?

I guess that depends on your definition of "suffering". There are literally billions of people on this planet who truly suffer on a daily basis. We're definitely talking First World Problem here. That said…

Yes, I've found it painful in a way to have to deal with questions that someone should have known better than to post.

But I'm not really sure it's possible to do much better. In many ways Stack Overflow is the perfect balance of community involvement and strictness. It *needs* to be a fully open resource, available to all. Short of some very expensive, very hard-to-write machine learning that can reliably filter out bad questions and answers, Stack Overflow just doesn't work unless we allow the worst, and rely on the community to stem the tide of crap.

And rely on the community we do. Which is a *very* important part of coping. Remember that there are dozens, hundreds, maybe even thousands of other people who feel the same way you do and who are contributing what time they are able to help keep things cleaned up.

If you feel overwhelmed, depressed, discouraged, whatever, just remember…**it's okay to take a step back**. Stack Overflow can get along without you, me, or any other single individual just fine. For the sake of your own mental health, don't spend time on Stack Overflow out of a sense of duty or obligation. Do what you can do happily, and leave the rest to others. This will make the contributions you do make more valuable, and will help avoid burnout.

For what it's worth, I have myself had to back off quite a lot from when I first started answering questions a year ago. I initially treated Stack Overflow almost as a full-time job, because I was using it to learn new APIs that I wanted to dive deeply in quickly. But after about six months of that, I needed to get back to doing real work, and at the same time I was feeling the onset of burnout.

So now, I restrict my involvement:

- I follow only one tag.
- With practically no exception, I do not look at any question that already has one answer.
- I almost never look at "fresh" questions, other than to check if they need improvement; I set aside reasonable blocks of time each day, and work my way back through the "newest" questions in the tag, opening the ones of interest in new tabs so I can deal with them sequentially. Most of the questions I wind up looking at are at least hours old, if not almost a day.
- I *do* look at questions that I feel have a high likelihood of needing improvement; usually I will comment and down/close vote as necessary. On occasion, I find a question that I myself am able to improve.
- I no longer spend time on questions that are likely to require a lot of research on my part; the exception being topics which I am still trying to learn and for which I feel such research will benefit me at least as much as it will the questioner.
  Doing a little bit of research to refresh my memory or provide specific details I wouldn't otherwise know off the top of my head is fine. I just won't spent a lot of time searching the web for something I'm not even sure I know is there or for which I'm not even sure I know what I'm looking for.

At this point, I find very few questions to spend time answering. Most of the time spent on Stack Overflow is in more of a curating capacity. But the questions I do find to answer tend to be ones of relatively high interest to me. This helps offset what would otherwise just be a grind, commenting and voting on post after post that are of supremely low quality.

And to be sure, such questions *do* exist. They do tend to get lost amongst the heaps of low quality, but they are there and if anything, their rarity makes finding them that much more pleasurable. :)

Answer (score -6):

What do you mean with "suffering"? Nobody is forced to contribute ;)

You should contribute only then when you feel you will have a true benefit from the exchange.

Comment: Suffering as in something akin to a 'gardener seeing his beloved garden in shambles after a brief hiatus'. My visits are more of muscle memory and average time spent is in now into seconds before I turn away...

Answer (score -38):

Perhaps the amount of beginner / low quality questions could be reduced by having a beginner section for all major programming languages. Within this section you could the most commonly frequently asked questions. Maybe within the categories it'd be good to split it down into different topics, e.g. For Android, one section could be "Storing data", another "Fragments", etc.

Quite a few people I talk to in my university classes are scared to post questions on to Stack Overflow as they've had bad experiences in the past where people weren't helpful and/or their question was rated down.

Comment: I like any idea which aims to kind of help filter/isolate those basic questions to those in the mood to answer them, but I think this one is tough because of the way tagging works -- it overlaps -- a question can still be tagged as `beginner` and still `c++`, e.g. Sections/wikis aren't mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Ike who says they need to be mutually exclusive? If questions overlap into other sections, then so be it as long as they are relevant to the topic they are included within I don't see the problem. I don't like the idea of tagging questions as "beginner" because what one developer considers as beginner might be considered a bit difficult for beginners by another developer.

Comment: I didn't downvote just there (I like any ideas to tackle this problem and I'd consider it incredibly rude to do in this context)! But I thought this thread was mostly about just kind of filtering out those questions in the first place. The way I see it is that unless the beginner-associated stuff is mutually exclusive with intermediate/advanced-stuff, then everyone will end up seeing them regardless.

Comment: I suppose you're looking at this more from the perspective of offering beginners a proper place -- to not intimidate them. I was looking at it more from not annoying and demotivating the advanced/intermediate types by always being exposed to the beginner/low-quality questions a hundred times a day. That's where I thought this kind of needs to be mutually exclusive to work -- from that intermediate/advanced perspective.

Comment: @Ike perhaps we need moderators to tag the questions as either beginner / intermediate / expert so if people are only interested in answering intermediate / expert questions, they can and so these same people wont be frustrated when seeing lots of beginner questions?

Comment: To those who are down voting my reply, this is exactly what I'm getting at with Stack Overflow. People get down voted and nobody leaves a reason why, I can neither learn from or benefit from people just down voting without leaving a comment on why they are down voting me. It just leaves me being less likely to reply to questions and ask questions in the future.

Comment: Dunno -- I personally liked the proposal to have a pre-screening process for questions from the lowest-rep users. It didn't go over so well (maybe I expressed my rationale poorly). I feel like that could help filter the bad questions -- not beginner ones, but "bad" are far more annoying than "beginner" (the laziest ones that want mind-readers). A good beginner question can be quite refreshing, and sometimes a beginner question can warrant a very deep and expert response.

Comment: Here's where my thoughts seemed alien to a lot of people -- I actually thought a pre-screening process, like what we have to review edits now, could actually make the site *more* beginner-friendly -- because they wouldn't immediately be exposed to the impatient community at large. If they ask a bad question, they could be rejected with a proper comment by someone in the mood to review it, not down-voted and have their question shut down 10 minutes within asking it.

Comment: @Ike I like your idea. Giving people feedback, especially when they're quite new to asking questions on Stack Overflow would be a great addition so people would learn how to ask good questions and how to avoid asking bad questions.

Comment: Not sure why you're getting downvoted.. the thought did cross my mind of having 2 layers. Good questions from the beginner layer get lifted to the upper layer via moderators or high rep users. Upvoting.

Comment: You are getting downvoted because you did not research your answer before you posted it.  Your suggestion has been posted **many** times before and always found lacking.  You can trivially google them with 'site:meta.stackexchange beginner section'.

Comment: _"Quite a few people I talk to in my university classes are scared to post questions on to Stack Overflow"_ - **good**. It should be mandatory to have read and memorized [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Every semester there's questions about syntax errors and errors that would have been spotted by the most basic debugging. Yet we have people answering those questions again and again.

Comment: @HansPassant just because it's been posted before doesn't mean that it shouldn't be discussed again. Perhaps the reason why it's been suggested so many times is because it might be a good solution?

Comment: @CodeCaster yes, I fully agree. Perhaps why questions like that come up so often is because the two questions you have linked aren't very prevalent for new users of the website?

Comment: Hmm, no, you posted this suggestion because you didn't research your answer.  Otherwise you'd know all the prior objections and be smart enough to give a new compelling reason why it should be considered.  As-is, the post causes the kind of fatigue that the OP is talking about.  I don't think he was looking for more examples :)

Comment: Perhaps a reminder to all those who have been down voting me: http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice also, it is stated on this website "Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps dangerously incorrect.". I feel that I put sufficient effort into my post by suggesting a solution to a very big problem for new users of SO.

Comment: This is not SO, this is meta. Two reminders to you: downvoting on meta works very differently, and a reality check is not intimidation.

Comment: @Gimby okay, you've stated that down voting works very differently on meta yet have made no effort to link me the source of where you have read this. I've done some research and found this "On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post itself." other than that, there's no other criteria for what you should down vote, only what you should up vote. This question wasn't tagged 'feature-request' so again, I don't know why people are down voting my answer.

Comment: @HansPassant also if my answer to this specific question has came up a lot, does that not suggest that this is a duplicate question?

Comment: @MarkOSullivan94 The reality of Meta is that people will vote on posts that propose a change to SO in the same way as if it were a feature request. The presence or absence of a tag changes nothing in practice. And no, moderators won't step in to police this.

Comment: @MarkOSullivan94 downvoting is NOT "not being nice". Break that out of your mind and your SO experience will improve :) (especially in meta, where voting is really, but REALLY different). Votes are never about the user, always about the post itself. In this instance, it's not a good suggestion, so people downvote.

Comment: @Patrice if the vote is not about the user then why is the score of the user related to the votes on their questions and answers? I have went from getting +12 in 3 other answers to now having -2 overall score due to this one answer which is deemed a bad answer. I can understand the concept of down voting a bad idea but is a bad idea better than no idea at all?

Comment: @MarkOSullivan94 the vote on your post is meant for your POST, not YOU. The impact it has on you isn't the same as what the vote means.

Comment: @Patrice but this is the problem, if the vote on my post is meant for my post and not me overall as a user of SO meta, then why is there a score on my profile which stands at -2 despite me having 3 good answers and 1 bad answer? This is what puts people off from putting forward answers. I put forward this answer today just trying to get involved with SO meta after browsing it but due to the response it's put me completely off posting another question or answer. This is SO's biggest problem.

Comment: @MarkOSullivan94 so, you posting what is seen as a bad answer by the community should have NO CONSEQUENCE to you? Rep (and score since they are related... on Meta it's different, but you get my drift) is an indication of how much the site trusts you, and how much good contributions you've made. The vote standing at -14 means "this contribution is bad". Your profile shows your contribution. No one is downvoting to have you look bad. People are downvoting because the contribution is considered bad. Now.. you say it's SO's biggest problem : how do we fix it?

Comment: @Patrice okay well since down votes are a major problem with SO, why doesn't SO disable down votes if the question / answer isn't scored 1 or higher? The best questions and answers will be up voted and given the votes they deserve and the people who ask the bad questions wont be put off from asking again. Alternatively, perhaps people should only be allowed to down vote if they post a comment under the question / answer as to why they were down voted. I wasn't informed why I was getting down voted until I asked, by that stage I had already -5 or so down votes.

Comment: @Patrice I only suggest this because I want to give more involved with SO myself. I wouldn't mind helping out answering beginner questions if people would have the decency to inform me why my question / answer is getting down voted and so I could be able to improve my question / answer. If I'm simply just getting down voted to oblivion every time I post, what's the point in posting when it'll leave me feeling demoralised and stupid for doing so?

Comment: @MarkOSullivan94 so how do we give feedback? it's "0 for not good enough for downvote, but also 0 for terrible questions"? That doesn't sound like it'll work. And forcing comments has been discussed even MORE than the "beginner section" and it's always lacking in substance. You will get downvotes with "b n2w[94ub420i" then, because people won't be bothered to comment. You come to stack, you ask a question. Shouldn't it be YOUR responsibility to figure out how to make your question on topic?

Comment: @MarkOSullivan94 the simple fact downvotes make you demoralized means you don't understand what they are about. The basis for the majority of downvotes is in the tooltip. For the rest, yeah sometimes you will get no justification, but often you will. commenting on a downvote (I did use to do it a LOT when I downvoted) ends up in a LOT of arguments (read codeCaster's answer, it happens REALLY often), so people end up not doing it. I understand that

Comment: @Patrice I think there's a fine line between "not good enough for down vote" and "good enough for a down vote", we shouldn't have those two categories. SO should have good questions or else, not good questions. No in betweens which means if your question has a score of 0, it isn't a good question. I think a lot more people would accept that than getting minus scores.

Comment: @Patrice also I don't see anything wrong with people wanting to ask those who down voted them why they were down voted. If you fail to get a job after going through the interview process, you're entitled to feedback, if I ask a bad question / give a bad answer should I not get tips from the seasoned veterans of SO on how I'm supposed to know how to improve it the next time? If you can't find out where you're going wrong, you're going to get constantly down voted and so there's no point in posting.

Comment: @MarkOSullivan94 Now, are you aware there is a question ban algorithm based off question score? So users who cannot post good questions end up not being able to post at all? How does that factor into your idea?

Comment: @MarkOSullivan94 Now, do we also force comments on upvotes? people upvote for the stupidest reasons... do we also need them to explain why it's good? Why should I comment on a question that is nothing but a code dump? Isn't it the user's responsibility to read the tour and the "how to ask good questions"? To me it sounds like it is. If I downvote and you obviously didn't read these articles, me pointing out you didn't read them won't help. Oh and btw, you are free to ASK to know why you got downvoted. I don't see why no one would be forced to answer though

Comment: @Patrice I'm unaware of this question ban algorithm, could you provide me with a link to an explanation of it? SO is about encouraging questions and answers, at least that is what I thought and so I don't see the relevance of having to be able to up vote comments. If I want to be up voted, I'll ask a good question or give a good answer. If I want to comment under a question and answer, I don't expect an up vote in return for it.

Comment: @MarkOSullivan94 so if you don't want to be upvoted, you post crap questions and they sit at 0? That doesn't make sense. And the algorithm is not know, because then people can play around to abuse how it's coded. We just know it checks your questions' standings, and if they are too low quality for the site, it doesn't let you in. and NOW we have the kicker : like most new users, you're under the impression Stack is there to provide help, so we should let questions come. Stack is meant to be a *high quality* repository of Q&As for future visitors. That's the goal of the site. DVs help with that

Comment: @MarkOSullivan94 http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th for the algo (or the best link you can get). With that, I'm done. It's fun to see you're not angry or anything and open to debate, but I'd suggest lurking a bit on meta before making too many conclusions about the website :). It's been established this way for good reasons that are justified. The fact these justifications aren't always apparent doesn't mean they are bad. On that note. Enjoy your day/weekend!

Comment: @MarkOSullivan94 "If you fail to get a job after going through the interview process, you're entitled to feedback" - no, that isn't how the world works. Sometimes you don't always get verbal feedback. Sometimes silence from the company (a downvote) is all the feedback you get. That's okay; take the feedback you do get, and learn from it. It's not a personal critique of you when you get a down vote, it is a (brief, vague) 'professional' criticism about your content. Why is it tied to your score? Because that lets you notice it, and learn from it.

Comment: It doesn't seem to have been mentioned here, among all the talk of voting, that votes on Meta don't affect your reputation at all.

Comment: I down voted this answer but also found [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275243/stack-overflow-basics-tutorial-style-minisite) for you.

Comment: @Josh Caswell: Probably because it's irrelevant.

Comment: Not when the answerer is concerned about the [effects of downvotes on his score](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310698/stack-overflow-fatigue-has-your-usage-motivation-dropped-off/310705#comment273723_310705), @BoltClock.