# Last-answer-first order when they haven't got votes

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, sorting

Lately I noticed a decline of quality in answers in a [game](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-reputation-fast-on-any-stack-exchange-site) that people are vying to provide "*just something*" to be the first. Also it is seen that the questions don't get enough attention when they are answered - at least once.

People seems to be solely focusing on gaining reputation even at the cost of the quality of the answer. You see a question, you do a simple search and come up with "try this" answer just to be the first. Sometimes they propose another way to do it than bothering much to find what really bugs the OP. There is a huge knowledge slip in this process.

I know people can down vote such answers. I have been doing this. But the practicality is that only one or two more answers will follow - the first one still get more up votes than the down ones. In this pattern the people get to choose the best from what's available than looking for the one that is really the best.

I would like to suggest in this context that **the order of the un-voted answers should be the last-one-first**. Here are the pros. You can comment/answer the cons.

1. Quickly coming up with "*just something*" as an answer doesn't work here. Because it anyway goes down.
2. If you try to be late and still give "*just something*" - you inevitably give time for someone who has something really good. The OP must have already chosen it. So the game is not about the time - but the quality.
3. Questions get more attention. Because the game is not over for the questions which has got one or two answers in their bags yet.
4. People has more time to think, search and test their answers before worrying too much about a lame answer that will jump in and steal all the votes and attention.

I have been using SO for a long time before I got interested about gaining reputation. Once I started, I thought "this is cool - it always keeps me very sharp". But I soon realized that the one who needs to provide the best is not the one to win always.

They talk about the problem [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310698/stack-overflow-fatigue-has-your-usage-motivation-dropped-off/310709#310709).

Comment: Meta SE duplicate [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9731)

Comment: @David - Thanks. But "Fastest Gun in the West Problem" only raises the issue.  I mention the issue after starting with a solution.

Comment: How about going to your tag pages and scrolling down to the forsaken lot 45 minutes aging and downwards. You will have plenty of time to be perhaps the only Answer for quite a while. Keep improving it. It will be your own little protected oasis. Just a thought.

Comment: @Drew - Thanks. I like this suggestion and I think it fulfills my sharpness-hunting. But generally, that doesn't bring someone a reward in the form of a green patch in his info bar area.

Comment: Well the mob has already passed it by. The op may shower you with appreciation. Fame and fortune may follow. And you won't feel the pressure of Answers flowing in around you. And don't forget to jazz it up with references and nice formatting, 10x the visitors to that page happen over time. Forget about the last 45 minutes.

Comment: @Drew - Unfortunately not everyone wants what I do. This degrades the quality of SO still.

Comment: I looked at 5 or 6 of your recent answers. They are short. They could be doubled or tripled in length easily without `TL;DR`. Sure, sometimes it feels like putting lipstick on a pig. But it is 90% psychology. Not try this, or see that. Make them feel like you care. Feel their pain.

Comment: @Drew - And did you look at my old answers? This is exactly what I'm talking about. Recent ones could have been better, long, more informative, etc . I'm talking about the climate that supports it. Just not only on me - but on the whole mass.

Comment: I agree. No argument here :)

Comment: And I really appreciate your suggestion. I took it personally and going to go along with it seriously.

Answer (score 6):

### I disagree.

The newest answer isn't necessarily the best answer.

Plenty of times I've seen users answer a relatively simple question an hour after it was posted, basically saying the *same* that existing answers do.

If anything, I'd sort them by post length. A longer answer implies that the user put more effort into the answer. (So let's dump a *massive* code block into the answer)

Seriously though, there's nothing more fair than sorting them randomly. Which is already how the "votes" sort works on answers with equal vote counts.

You can also sort by "Active", which shows the answer with the most recent activity at the top.

Comment: Thanks. Certain dynamics are already formed in this race. You provide a really good answer to a question which already has few answers and few total votes - there is a doubt if your answer will even be seen by anyone. Because the first-to-first pattern drives away attention.

Comment: The question is not about "what you can do". It is rather about "what the average are doing"

Comment: Then I disagree even more. Showing the last answer first for _everyone_, by default, only encourages users to post low quality answers on old questions.

Comment: The only aim of a low-quality answer is reputation. By the time this hypothetical low-quality answer comes in the old question's way - a quality answer is already provided and even hailed. No use of giving the low-quality answer then - because the old games simply doesn't work now. Don't forget that your time investment in answering is now safe since there are no lame jump ups.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not convinced that your feature request will actually solve the problem.  The problem with FGITW isn't so much the answers being submitted quickly, rather it is with onlookers of the question immediately upvoting answers that are helpful (enough).  So even with your proposed solution, the first answer can still get a few upvotes way before the next "better" answer is submitted.  I think this is because of the views of other users who are considering answering the question when they see the "1 new answer" banner.  Upon loading the answer, they see it is what they were going to submit and upvote it as helpful.

Also, what is the difference between 2 distinct fastest-gun answers that are submitted *seconds* apart?  I highly doubt an extra 5 seconds in post time is at all a good indicator of being more thought out.

Finally, your feature request is lacking on a few details that I feel are important in implementation:

- How are 0-vote answers ordered with respect to other 0-score answers (+1/-1)?
- Is there any timing restriction on the answer ordering?  For example if a question gets a 0-vote answer within 15 minutes and another new answer later in the week?
- How do you handle edits to posts?  Do they count as "newer" or does everything revolve around the original posting timestamp?

Comment: The whole point here is to discourage "just something" coming in as an answer just to compete with the time. Something low quality, if comes first, can bring reputation now. So, that is the order of the day in SO. But the proposed change will discourage this. So, as you predict, there won't be very quick + low quality answers.

Comment: Answers to your questions: (1). They should be treated the same (2/3). Just order by the time.