# Feature request: sort answers by descending dates

Tags: feature-request, sorting

Would it be possible to implement a feature to **sort answers in a descending fashion** in addition to the current ascending feature that is offered. Such a feature would allow for more up-to-date answers to be seen first and potentially **re-incentivize continued participation by "experts"** that currently don't have to answer any new questions due to receiving a steady and bountiful "income" of reputation from old answers.

Comment: Isn't the "active" sort meant for that?

Comment: I'm not an expert but it seems to me that "active" records any user-enteractment with a question that has passed a threshold of votes which is a sorting method which naturally favors less-helpful or outdated answer. @rene

Comment: Kind of related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310890

Comment: Note that unless you are familiar with Stack Overflow's code base, saying whether something is "easy to implement" is unlikely to make you any friends among those who maintain it. I know I get rather rowdy when a pointy-haired manager tells me something is easy with no knowledge...

Comment: Is there not a userscript out there that will add a "newest" sort order to the sort button group?

Comment: You should soon be able to review https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers which should satisfy your interest for newest answers. Side note: you probably should remove your rant about users having too much reputation presumably not giving your/questions you are interested in from the question...

Comment: Please also consider [edit] post to clarify why "Active" is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Maybe related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294637/feature-request-introduce-an-optional-sort-option-for-answers-that-lets-new-go

Comment: I'm not convinced this would do much to incentivize participation, because most users will likely continue to sort by votes. This would probably be more useful for curation purposes...except the Active sort already handles that better, since it also catches bad edits.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Do you have access to any data that would suggest most users sort by votes? I have access to no data that would suggest this and I personally do not sort in this way.

Comment: That data is not public and this data request from 2014: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237973/how-many-users-have-changed-their-default-sort-by is unanswered.

Comment: @ChefJulian It's obvious, SE by default sorts answers by votes, so that means most users will continue to sort by votes, rather than active. We sort by votes default because that's the way content rises to the top. So there really is no need for "data".

Comment: I really don't understand the point about participation. The people who already get a steady stream of rep aren't really in here *for* that rep. In most cases, they've answered thousands of questions. Honestly, rep is much less of a motivation than low-rep users seem to think it is. Once you have around 3k most of the new privileges are mostly irrelevant. Once you're over 25k, there aren't any new privileges. The only people I see talking about getting more and more rep is...new-ish users who don't have a lot of it.

Comment: It is the opposite sort order to *"Oldest"*, so logically the name should be *"Newest"*. So an alternative feature request could be to change *"Oldest"* to *"Newest"* (and the corresponding sort order). That would (probably) make the *development effort* nearly trivial (there would a flood of meta question because of the (almost) literally moved cheese, but we can handle that (thanks, close votes!)).

Comment: The problem here is that this is easily implemented with a userscript (just `reverse` the NodeList of answers). In addition, old questions like the branch prediction question has a well-known old answer that appears on top no matter the filter. Placing the new ones first is useless because the question was already answered.

Answer (score 11):

This could be a nice-to-have feature for some people. Whether or not it's worth the developer's time is the main factor here though. The question is: will enough users benefit from this feature? You'll need to provide a valid argument to support this.

For me personally, sorting by "Active" (as [suggested by rene](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/403462/feature-request-sort-answers-by-descending-dates#comment812856_403462) in the comments) is good enough for this purpose. If I'm interested in the most up-to-date answer, I *want* to see answers that were recently edited, (not just added) because they might contain updated information that is more useful and more up-to-date than a recently posted answer even if the edited answer was originally posted, say, 10 years ago.