# Policy on retaliatory downvoting

Tags: discussion

I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241491/python-urllib2-or-requests-post-method), and someone commented with a non-answer. I told him his answer didn't answer the question, and he told me to google it in a pretty hostile manner, so I flagged his comment as unconstructive. In response, he downvoted the whole question.

I'm relatively new here, but my impression is that moderators and users make a sincere effort to avoid/prevent rudeness. Downvoting a question because you're unable to answer it seems like the kind of thing we're trying to avoid.

I need an answer to the question I posted (which is a crystal-clear question, by the way), but since it's been downvoted people presumably won't look at it anymore.

Is there something I can do about this situation other than posting here?

Comment: And why do you know he downvoted you?  Voting is anonymous.  Maybe someone else downvoted you?

Comment: There's no reason to downvote the question. As I said, what I'm asking is crystal clear (although apparently the question is a stumper). It's pretty obvious it was him. Look at his comments.

Comment: there are 21 people who viewed your question at this point.  Any one of them could have downvoted.  Accusing the people who comment on your post of being the downvoters is not productive.  Yes someone downvoted you, but you don't know if it was him or anyone else who happened to look at your post.

Comment: Looks to me like he was trying to help you, and providing some good guidance.

Comment: "Then head to google and find somewhere that does"

is an acceptable answer on stackoverflow?

Comment: @MarcAdler No, but it is not an answer, it's a response in a comment :)

Comment: Then why are there flags for "unconstructive" responses next to comments? I'm not trying to be difficult. I just don't understand.

Comment: You're more than welcome to flag comments as unconstructive. But that isn't what you just asked. And I don't think that comment was unconstructive, in any case.

Comment: @MarcAdler but the comment was constructive.  It is telling you to do more research. While I respect you feel the commenter was being rude, I think you are mistaking curtness for rudeness.  The comment to use google was hardly rude.  It was telling you to use Google to help you solve your problem.  Stack Overflow is not a "fix my bug for me" kind of site.  There is an expectation that the asker has done a lot of research and really understands the issue.

Comment: I explicitly said I had googled the problem. He initially said "google it yourself," and then added a link to a site which I had already specifically said in my question I had looked at. (My guess is he didn't actually read my question very carefully.) 

As you can see from the question, I demonstrated a knowledge of the problem and wasn't asking people to "fix a bug for me." I amply fulfilled the expectation of having done a lot of research.

Comment: The site does contain the information you need though. Somehow you just don't understand it. Perhaps if you could explain what parts you don't understand it would be clearer how we could help you. Otherwise your question looks like *how do I foo*? And the commenter is telling you *here's a site that describes how to foo* At this point it looks like you'd be better off reading a book rather than trying to use a Q&A site.

Comment: `I told him his answer didn't answer the question, ... I flagged his comment as unconstructive.` How not to make friends and influence people

Comment: @MarcAdler I don't know python, so I can't comment on the quality or lack there of on your specific post.  All I can do is try to help you understand Stack Overflow.  And similarly, I can't comment on your research, but simply saying "I googled the problem" is usually not evidence of "doing your research".  In your question you need to demonstrate that you understand your problem and why it is failing and what you don't know to solve it.  If you do that, you usually won't get downvoted that much

Comment: @Laurel I don't think 1 is a sudden flood!

Comment: As the commenter in question, I'm not convinced it's a good or *"crystal-clear"* question; you refer in comments to attempts you've made but there's no MCVE and it's not obvious quite where you're stuck. It's your job to adapt generic instructions to your specific task, it doesn't scale very well to have a separate Q&A for every site one could post form data to. As to whether I'm one of the downvoters... they're anonymous for a reason, that's nobody's business but mine!

Comment: I think the problem here was that the OP isn't familiar with what bits of a HTML form make up the resulting POST request, which to know is standard fare for most web devs but not exactly intuitive to Google, so a question asking this comes across as disingenious/lazy/vague even though it may not be. I'd just forget the whole discussion about downvotes, and try and see whether the question can be salvaged or answered now.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I did mention how to see the request in [my first comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37241491/python-urllib2-or-requests-post-method#comment62012159_37241491)

Comment: @MarcAdler FWIW I *did* read the question. I linked to the *specific part* of the tutorial that covers what you're trying to do, having told you what the task was called so that you could research it further yourself and refine the question to be more specific. I'm interested in *teaching people to fish*, rather than just handing out code dumps.

Comment: @Pekka웃 "I don't understand how POST" works (which seem to be problem OP is actually facing) could be a bit too broad for SO. At very least question need to be edited to show that it is the problem before it can be answered...

Comment: @MarcAdler note that "all the tutorials online use completely useless made-up example urls" sound like rants and make very negative impression from the beginning of the post. You may be looking for such reaction explicitly, but ranting rarely gets positive votes. Additionally you essentially prohibit answers that are self-contained in SO post as you seem to require complete server side url to POST to and get response...

Comment: Thanks for all these comments. Yes, I was frustrated, because I'm a beginner and despite SO's stated goal of being welcoming, there really isn't any way for a beginner to ask beginner questions. It's a bit of a catch-22. Until you know enough about a problem, you can't ask questions here. You have to spend hours reading through documentation aimed at non-beginners, trying to piece together enough knowledge to qualify as knowledgeable enough to ask a question, even though someone could answer your Q in two seconds if beginners were allowed to ask dumb questions. But they're not. C'est la vie!

Comment: @MarcAdler 'even though someone could answer your Q in two seconds if beginners were allowed to ask dumb questions' no.  What would happen is that such a beginner would enter a massive queue of other beginners, mostly waiting for the same set of answers to the same set of questions, while the resource for answering them - the skilled and experienced engineers, would give up and ignore SO.

Comment: Tour, first sentence: 'Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers.'.  Doesn't say anything about 'provides free tuition for beginners'.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Occasional single downvotes happen to everyone; there is nothing you can do about them, nor should there be. It's best to forget them right away.

People are free to vote whichever way they want, for any reason they want, as long as there is no pattern of targeting (as in, someone downvoting a lot of your contributions specifically).

If you start getting a *lot* of mysterious downvotes and you suspect they all come from one user, wait 24 hours for the automated process  to kick in that normally takes care of these things. If that doesn't help, flag for moderator attention.

Regarding the specific situation, I agree it was a somewhat unfortunate set of circumstances and misunderstandings. I don't blame you, nor the other guy, for being a bit annoyed.

However, as the asker, it's always good to keep your cool even when faced with comments that come across as snarky. Remember that you're the one who wants something from the community! That doesn't mean you have to be subservient or take any abuse hurled at you (for true abuse, always flag as "rude/abusive" ore get help from a moderator), but a polite response explaining what exactly you don't understand or what doesn't work for you is always a good path to take even when you're rudely told to look up X, or just do Y.

This investment in self-restraint is not necessarily for the benefit of the other user, it's a public act: other users coming by (who might be able to help you) could be quick to misinterpret your annoyance (even if justified) as arrogance - or be impressed by your self-control and politeness, and go the extra step to help you out.

Comment: Great advice. I'd post another question suggesting that SO create a Beginners Board, but I'm afraid I would incur the community's wrath again, so I'll just keep my mouth shut!

Comment: @MarcAdler: You would incur wrath, but not for the reason that you'd expect:  you'd be down-voted for asking a question that had been asked many times before without first researching it. Please search this meta site, and again you'll see that this suggestion has been made before, and was felt to not be worthwhile. Here's [one such example](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254381/should-we-fork-stack-overflow-for-beginning-programmers).

Comment: I did search — in Area 51. Another beginner's mistake.

Comment: I will point out that the responses to the question you linked to basically prove the OP's point. Utterly unconvincing, pissing-contest stuff, instantly disproven by looking at the Japanese language site. Experts (like yours truly) respond to beginner questions politely all the time. Can you imagine a "no dumb questions" policy there? Granted, learning Japanese is many orders of magnitude harder than learning to program, but still. Beginners should be able to ask dumb questions.

Comment: 'learning Japanese is many orders of magnitude harder than learning to program'.  You can justify that?

Comment: @MarcAdler I have already suggested a 'Bginners Board', but outside of SO.  You are cordially invited to sign up.  You will have to continually reply to the same set of questions from posters who can not, or will not, understand your answers.  You are generally expected to work 24/7 with no breaks, though for the first month, or until you die of self-neglect, you get one hour off a week.

Comment: @MarcAdler worth bearing in mind that the 50 newest questions on Japanese go back to a week ago; on SO, that's **nine minutes**.

Comment: During which, this comes in, AKA' teach me Japanese': http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37250342/timer-threads-os

Comment: or, from earlier 'I have a problem learning Japanese - fix it': http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37249777/how-do-i-read-and-print-the-first-5-integers-from-a-txt-file-in-c

Comment: ..or 'I had a child who knew Japanese, but he died.  How can I talk to him?': http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37248812/using-a-variable-after-program-execution

Comment: Turning Japanese I think I'm turning Japanese I really think so...

Comment: @MartinJames Yes, I can justify it. It takes many years of study to master Japanese. You can learn a programming language in a few months. Yes, I know that the comparison is slightly apples-to-oranges, but learning Japanese is still harder.

Comment: @MarcAdler well, if by 'learning to program', you mean 'learn a programming language', the quite possibly, you are correct.