# Why can't we be more aggressive on low-quality posts?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, low-quality-posts, quality-improvement

(I'm making an effort to keep the number of links down here to keep any meta effect to a minimum.)

This site is going downhill in terms of post quality. [I don't think that is up for debate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow). My question is why aren't we allowed to be more aggressive in cleaning up these things?

I recently got a flag ban for three declined flags in seven days. One of the flags was my mistake. I voted to close as unclear, and then I looked again, and the question does make some sense. However, two of them I believe I was right in flagging, because the questions were later closed for a very similar reason. One I mod-flagged as belonging on SoftwareRecs, and it was closed as off-topic. The other I mod-flagged as a very low quality post with multiple reasons, and it was also closed later as off-topic. Why be so critical of an aggressive approach to low quality posts? What does it matter what the reason for closing is if the question has problems?

I feel very much like [LadyCygnus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252993). I won't reiterate their sentiments here, but between the difficulty in getting rep in the tags I follow (either very low traffic or a whole lot of low quality traffic) and the overall low quality of posts, I am not very thrilled about helping out here. I came as an answerer, not as one of the many many help vampires. In about three days, when I get the Fanatic badge, I will probably quit (at least temporarily for some time).

Then there are users who answer low quality questions. Can't we discourage this? I would downvote, but I don't have the rep to spend on this.

This is not about my particular case. It's about **"What can we change so that Stack Overflow is the best it can be?"**, which means **reducing low quality posts**.

**Update**: I removed the part about a privilege to ask questions, as it probably is not practical.

Comment: While this is an important topic, this stuff has been discussed...kinda a lot. E.g., "can't we make it a privilege to ask questions so that only those who help others get helped" -> [Should Stack Overflow be more restrictive about new user registrations?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324220) I'd like to see more done too, but I'm not sure what this particular post adds.

Comment: @Josh, that is a good question you linked. Hard to find related posts on here. I'll take a closer look when I have time.

Comment: @oldtechaa Hard to find related posts? You're being sarcastic, right?

Comment: @torazaburo, I'm not being sarcastic. I looked in all the suggested related posts for things that looked like what I was asking, and I even search explicitly for similar wording. I don't find the search filters to be well-developed.

Comment: @oldtechaa Well, you could start off with http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324072/how-to-lure-professionals-to-stack-overflow/324090#324090.

Comment: @torazaburo, those are excellent comments, and I agree with your point of view heartily. I want to know, just like you, what SO can do just to keep the answerers it already has, not to mention getting new ones. With all these questions recently, I sure hope something comes of it, because I've seen multiple users get so frustrated they've left, and I'm soon to be one of them.

Comment: I just found [this](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/595/176764) where _Jeff Atwood himself_ agreed that __the key people are answerers, not the askers.__

Comment: Perhaps you can replace the "aggressive" in your title with a more positively sounding term such as "proactive" or "decisive"?

Comment: @Rad, I could. I don't know, because I think SO is facing a critical time. Either we become more aggressive, or we become irrelevant. In many of the other discussions about it, people say we need an aggressive or radical approach to the problem. Personally, I almost feel that at least in some tags, no matter how aggressive we are, nothing will help. But please take a look at the link I posted above in my comment; no aggressiveness, no answerers, no SO.

Comment: I agree about minimum reputations. I think a new question about post quality on _Meta_ should require 2K minimum `/me runs away cackling`.

Comment: It's a matter of perception. Jeff Atwood's "... **aggressively* closing *unworthy* or *uninteresting* questions .." is exactly the kind of wording people get upset about - you know, the whole inflammatory "soup nazi" types of discussion. Changing it to "swift action to close and remove questions that don't fit the SO model" sounds ever so more friendly.

Comment: Recently I did much more answering of good questions instead of administring the site - It's more fun and life time is limited.So I totally like to aggressively work on low quality posts as long as they are really low quality and somebody else does it...

Comment: Without knowing any specifics, it would seem that you are getting those automated bans simply because you are still uncertain about how to moderate these kind of crap questions. Next time, you could ask for some "live coaching" in the [SO close vote review chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers), before you flag something. Otherwise you could also lay low with flags until you have enough rep to cast close votes yourself. At that point the system is much more lax: an incorrectly cast close vote will simply drown in the votes by other high rep users, no penalty.

Comment: Also note (regarding your migration mod-flag) that a very important guideline is "*don't migrate crap*". Always make sure that you only suggest migrating good posts, and always instruct the asker about finding out if their question is on-topic at the receiving end in case you suggest reposting to a sister site. See for instance [this post](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users) for frustrations caused by overzealous migrations from SO.

Comment: What do you mean by "flag"? You should vote to close bad questions.  Save flags for more serious problems.

Comment: I have to say, anyone who's first ever question is down voted and closed, should be automatically banned the same moment that the question is closed or goes below -2 with no chance of this ban ever being lifted.

Comment: Stackoverflow looks more yahoo-overflow every single day.  SO has become the same as the sites that it was built to replace.

Comment: @JK, I don't have CVs yet.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337098/why-dont-we-just-delete-crappy-questions?cb=1

Answer (score 50, accepted):

> One of the flags was my mistake. I voted to close as unclear, and then I looked again, and the question does make some sense. However, two of them I believe I was right in flagging, because the questions were later closed for a very similar reason.

So the system worked? Our **tempered** collective judgement ensured a legitimate question was not improperly handled, and the illegitimate ones were properly closed?

It's good to treat these cases with a certain level of caution, because it is good to avoid false positives. What if we as a community had been overly head strong and mishandled that one legitimate question?

If you had an overly aggressive spam filter that got 100% of spam but also mistakenly deleted 10% of your important emails, that would be really bad.  Of course we are not talking about the same kind of automated process, but basically it's good to temper our aggressiveness and try to give the benefit of doubt. Judgement calls aren't always clear, or sometimes various factors such as subject matter expertise result in false positives.

Bottom line, is any changes to this really would have to take a detailed look at many of these specific scenarios and see if it would make them better or worse. I don't think as a generalized guideline we should be trying to be more aggressive. There might be specific scenarios we can address and provide concrete guidelines (and often on Meta those are addressed and serve as a reference for handling those scenarios in the future).

> can't we make it a privilege to ask questions so that only those who help others get helped?

No. Many people are not yet at the skill level yet where they can contribute useful answers that are born from practical experience. I remember when I was first learning to program, and perusing C++ programming forums, long before Stack Overflow, I thought to myself: "Man it would be great if I knew enough to help others out they way they've helped me." After a year or so I could help answer some of the more straightforward posts dealing with: "Why am I getting this compiler error?" Up until that point, I had nothing to contribute.

Additionally, Stack Overflow is such that the more common and simple questions are often a resource to future visitors, and duplicates are likely to be closed. So unlike what you you might see in forums where novice users can at least answer some of the more common simple questions, on Stack Overflow there are less and less of these types of questions. For older, well-traveled tags, a lot of the questions left open for answers are more complicated and nuanced and would be out of reach of a novice user to answer.

With the mechanic you propose, it would isolate them to only more experienced programmers, and I don't think that is what Stack Overflow is about. We do want them to understand what is appropriate for the site, and how to ask good questions. **However, simply preventing someone from asking questions until they prove themselves through answers, will alienate a large audience of legitimate users only to avoid a few bad apples.**

> the difficulty in getting rep in the tags I follow
>
> not as one of the many many help vampires

I think you are setting yourself up for disappointment with this mentality. **This is kind of a life lesson in not letting your enjoyment of an activity hinge on outcomes that are out of your control.** Contribute the way you think is best for the community, but realize it is a community, and the outcome will be a collective result of the community.

Focus on doing what you enjoy, and don't concern yourself with the outcomes. If you feel like someone is a "help vampire", then simply don't answer their question. Yes it adds minor clutter to the site, but if they are a help vampire, then their question is probably overly specific and unlikely to benefit others. If so, it will not be very prominent and the clutter will be minor as it gains no votes. If someone answers, that's their time invested. You have invested nothing other than perhaps time making a quick skim of the question. If many people ultimately come to the question and upvote it, you might think: "OMG how horrible this awful question and it's answer are getting upvoted", but usually people upvote when they find the question and answer has helped them in some way.

In the long term, they make their way to the question via googling, and quickly leave it if it doesn't help them, and when it does help them, they upvote.  If it's getting upvoted, then it is serving as a useful future reference to others, and isn't as terrible as one might frame it to be. The site is fairly self correcting based on voting alone.

If you think it is a bad question and feel a downvote or flag is appropriate given the site's guidelines, do so. If you feel your one or two reputation is more valuable than issuing a downvote, then that's a value/benefit choice you make. If however you feel like this frustrates you to not see the outcomes you hoped for in all cases, perhaps you should invest your participation some other way.

When me and my brother used to get mad and scream at video games, my dad would always poke his head in the room and say: "Maybe you should do something else for a little bit?" We were usually pretty annoyed at this advice, so you're probably pretty annoyed at my advice, again probably not the response you hoped for, but I think in retrospect my father's advice was probably good advice.

It's the same reason I try not to get into political discussions with people, because no one is going to change their mind as the result of an argument, and so the outcome will never be one I am happy with.

Participate in a way that is rewarding to you. Don't think so much in terms of reputation or what others are doing, and more in terms of the value to others you can offer. Offer that value where you see it is valued and appreciated.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/262221/why-cant-stack-overflow-question-asking-be-more-like-yahoo/262226#262226

Comment: If a borderline question gets closed when it maybe should not have, the downside is **far** less than an important mail going into spam. So that's a bad example. There are already existing mechanisms for closing questions, such a dupehammers, that might be miused/abused; shall I assume you are in favor are eliminating those also? In addition, there are readily-available mechanisms for re-opening questions closed in error. So your whole arguments sort of falls apart.

Comment: This is a good suggestion to participate how you find it rewarding. I think that means I will at least quit [tag:perl] where the majority of these questions are. Unfortunately, that's most of my traffic. I think I will still take a break from SO though.

Comment: @torazaburo "shall I assume you are in favor are eliminating those also?" You would assume wrong. I stated I felt it worked well as it were and didn't make any suggestions to change that. I acknowledge there are cases mishandled, but meta has been effective at addressing those with guidelines. False positives are very bad, because someone contribute legitimate effort and someone's misinterpretation of guidelines has interrupted what is normally a smooth process. **I wouldn't diminish someone's contribute to be less than an email**, and I do think false positives are that bad.

Comment: @torazaburo It's not simply a matter of some borderline question getting wrongly closed, though. It may be a well-meaning but misguided new user who could become a valuable member of the community getting wrongly diagnosed as a help vampire, and being so upset by their reception on SO that they never return. Whereas a true help vampire will not be phased by anything short of a wooden stake through the heart: even if you question-ban them they'll just create a new account. So I prefer it if our procedures err on the side of _not_ alienating potentially good new members.

Comment: "After a year or so I could help answer some of the more straightforward posts..."  I would *love* to see an analysis of SO user account timelines, and how a typical account's ratio of questions/answers changes over time.

Comment: "Many people are not yet at the skill level yet where they can contribute useful answers that are born from practical experience." Let's not overlook people like me, who (think) they have the skills to answer usefully, but who work in the same tags that Jon Skeet and other rep-titans have been working in for years. It seems very rare to find a non-duplicate, pure-Java question that hasn't already been answered well.

Comment: @PM2Ring, our procedures also still have to allow for what answerers want; otherwise we lose them.

Comment: @oldtechaa: Certainly! But one thing that answerers want is a better (good question asker) / (help vampire) ratio. My point above is that it can be hard to tell if a new user who's asked a poor question has the potential to be guided into becoming a good question asker, or if they're just another HV. If we scare them off, they may never come back. And if they don't come back, they probably _weren't_ a HV, because they aren't easy to get rid of.

Comment: @Jeutnarg Yes, on forums semi-novice users can begin to help answer simpler questions(that are usually repeats of old questions), but here the simple questions have long been answered, and duplicates get closed. So for well traveled tags it is somewhat harder for semi-novice users to gain rep from answers.

Answer (score 23):

There are a number of us that **are** very aggressive on low quality posts. In fact, some users, like me, probably can't be more aggressive than we already are, since we have a limited number of votes/flags per day.

I use all of my close votes up per day, most of the time. And I'm not even drawing off [the list of several thousand open, off topic recommendation questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/280085/323179) I have on hand.

Close votes are a bit different than flags. You only get 50 of them daily, and they replace the close flags. You also get to keep your flags, but I've found that I usually can't use them all up every day. If your close vote is the only one on the question for 14 days, it dies (and you'd need to use another one).

Unfortunately, your close vote pool will not grow like your flag pool does (as an avid flagger, I have the max 100 flags per day).

It's not too hard to get the rep needed to close vote. There are a number of cool privileges you get along the way, like the ability to view score breakdowns or the ability to edit without suggestion. I have edited a large number of posts (some of these were just retags, if there weren't other problems), and I hope it did something to improve the quality.

Close votes, like *most* other forms of community moderation require a few other people in order to do anything. But I found another option.

When a question has 0 score, 0 answers, and is at least a month old, it can be down voted. And then, after the scripts run, the question will be deleted without the need for anyone else's intervention. You have *40* free down votes for questions per day (assuming you vote for nothing else).

While my close votes are idle in the CV queue, I find that down voting works wonders. I have been using it for those questions that were poorly tagged and fell through the cracks as a result. It should be effective for your low-traffic tags, too.

---

There is one flaw with my method. Like you observed, it is a problem when these low quality questions are answered. Just one answer foils [the Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) from deleting the question when its score drops. It's not always a bad thing, since there are good (or at least OK) questions that have a negative score (one of my own questions is hanging on at -1 because of an answer).

I think it would be a fantastic idea to broaden our coverage of VLQ (or NAA) to allow us to delete the answers to off topic questions more easily (like we do with "thanks" answers already). Of course, we need to be **very** careful with how we go about doing this, but I think it could be a great thing to do. There are a lot more users between 500 and 3k rep that can work to delete these answers in the low quality queue.

Take [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29906690/6083675), for example  <sup><sub>*waits for meta effect*</sub></sup>. Neither of these users have stayed around, but that stupid answer prevents the question from being deleted naturally. I put a VLQ flag on the answer a while ago, and it was disputed. Yes, it does answer the question, but the question should have been posted to Facebook support or Yahoo Answers, not Stack Overflow.

---

I think the other thing I want to mention is the fact that asking questions here is simply unrewarding unless you're going to be a help vamp. On other sites on the network, I don't need to spend **days** on a question before I post it. I don't get down votes I can't explain. I don't need to be hesitant asking questions.

I'm currently sitting on not one, but TWO drafts of questions for Stack Overflow, one of which I also have a self answer for. I'm just too terrified to post them because of how this site has treated my questions in the past (I may also have been revenge down voted recently, but I'm not sure; the script did nothing).

I know that some people are similarly turned off by asking questions, where they use a separate account just for asking. But I don't want it to come to that for me. I want to ask good questions and get the rep I deserve for my good contributions.

We are in severe deficit of good questions, the ones where the process of answering is reward even without getting any rep. But we also need to reward these questions (and their answers) with up votes, so that their owners can gain the privileges needed to keep the site healthy for more questions like that in the future.

Comment: The proper action on the question you posted is to vote to close. Have you done so? (I don't see any besides mine, but it could have aged out.)

Comment: This is a good answer, but I was more asking why the valid (albeit slightly mis-categorized) flags are treated roughly when anyone can see it's a bad question. I was also asking if there is any way to keep the site from just declining into 100% muck. I don't think there is a way to fix it, between an ever more selfish world and what you said about being unrewarding to ask questions here. I actually do find it rewarding to ask my real, difficult questions here (which is a very small percentage of every problem I run into) because I like to see the community's reaction.

Comment: While I don't have the rep for close votes, and I have 11 flags/day, I've actually tried cleaning up some older questions in my favorite tags with your Roomba method, so thanks for the tip. If no other answers come in soon, I will probably be accepting AaronLS's answer, because it more addresses how I personally can deal with this aggressively __and__ effectively. I'd still like more discussion about how we could change things on the site itself, but I think that will probably happen in the various linked questions. Thanks for the answer, Laurel.

Comment: A few things come to mind here: if your rep has been affected by serial voting and the reversal script did not kick in, flag one of the affected posts for a moderator and explain the problem, they will reverse it manually if needs be. In relation to your draft questions, post away! At 3K rep you need not fear the odd downvote or two. I would recommend having a line at which you do not care about downvotes, such as 5K - it is liberating to no longer care about it. The line for me was 10K, since I was curious about the mod tools (and I don't even use them now).

Comment: Delete other people's answers ? What else? Good or bad is relative,why do you think you can add such a powerful tool to all individuals and have it used properly? This bugs me because the  wave of down votes that have no reason is still a problem and ive seen it happen to questions  that get over 100 upvotes after a bit.now what happens if you let individuals delete posts/answers too?

Comment: @Virgil You do know that the LQPQ already exists, right? And 10k+ users already have the ability to cast delete votes. Nothing is new, and the only change I suggest is how we treat *off-topic* answers to *off-topic* questions (specifically those with a score close enough to the -1 required by Roomba).

Comment: @Laurel I thought you wanted direct control over deletion process for individuals,and it seems i have misunderstood. I apologize.

Comment: @halfer Yes, 10k is the last great perk. But I think the reason down votes disturb me so much is because I rarely get up votes, especially after the first 30 minutes. My record "high score" for one SO post is 7 (now 6 `:(`). I was planning to use "contact us" to report things but got distracted.

Comment: @Laurel: the only way to acquire rep (IMO) is to be a full and unreserved member of the community. I think my rep has increased in net terms, despite the odd downvote, because I have persistently posted questions and answers. This has not been much extra effort, since I was mostly doing that research anyway, and the process has often has helped me where I genuinely have not been able to resolve something on my own.

Comment: Maintaining your old questions is helpful too - people do sometimes notice when post owners go back to tend and improve. It is appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

> What does it matter what the reason for closing is if the question has problems?

It matters because the end goal shouldn't be - and, I hope, isn't - to just eliminate the low quality posts. The goal should be to turn the people who post low quality crap into productive users who contribute high quality content.

In order to do that the reasons for their questions being closed need to provide them with useful information they can act on to improve their current post and which will assist them in getting it right the first time around when they come to post questions in future. Flagging or voting to close isn't just a housekeeping exercise, it should also be a teaching one.

In most cases that is likely a losing battle. However, for the few cases where we can win I think it's worth getting it right.

If a question is so obviously bad that it needs to be removed with extreme prejudice then it shouldn't be difficult to pick the *correct* reason to vote (or flag) to close. If you're struggling to pick the right reasons then you might want to consider that you're not as qualified to judge as you think you are, and therefore need to go back and look again at what is acceptable on the site and what each of the specific flag reasons are meant to be used for (which is the purpose of a temporary ban on flagging).

Comment: "what each of the specific flag reasons are meant to be used for" > if it's not immediately obvious the problem lies in the name or the attached description.

Comment: We have no shortage of questions, so turning away some questioners who *might* contribute later could well be worthwhile.

Answer (score -12):

I have a great idea. Why not have two sections on SO. A place where beginners can ask questions, where they don't have any technical knowledge, and the mods are not so aggressive, and a professional section where the questions have to be formed in a better way.

when you first join you will join the beginner section and then progress to the professional section over time, once you have learned to form better questions, and have attained a bit of knowledge.

I am not quite sure how this would work in practice however.

Comment: It's been discussed before ([example](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254381)). The problem is, which experts want to answer questions in the "crap questions" section, when the "good questions" section is available?

Comment: An alternative: Review each post from a new user **before it's posted**. We already have a review queue for "First Posts"; it just needs to be modified so that the question isn't visible to other users until it's been approved or improved.

Comment: You've posted your answer on wrong section :)... I like your duplicate proposal, also for reasons you may not find so appealing - post bad question, get even worse answers and get expelled from whatever school you are in. End result - higher quality of people who graduate.

Comment: In practice SO would work just like forums that have a be-nice policy. People ask crap and they get crap answers. Pardon the crassness, I can't sugarcoat it because it really is that bad in my experience.

Comment: Now I see why people are putting their discussion in comments rather than an answer. You can't be down voted if you use a comment. Why people are down voting me for making a suggestion I do not know. They really must have too much time on their hands.

Comment: @ThomasWilliams - it is META.SO, not SO itself if you did not notice. Votes here generally mean agreement or disagreement with answer and there is no reputation involved. (Note that this particular post also getting downvotes for proposing something that was discussed many times)

Comment: Thank you Alexei. I am pretty new to SO so I am not totally aware what things mean, which is why my suggestion was made. However I do notice on some of my questions I have posted people tend to comment rather than answer. Sometimes the comment is really helpful and because they have made a comment I can't upvote them, which is a shame.

Comment: You can upvote them, it just doesn't help them any. Usually people comment if they're not sure about the answer. If their comment is the answer, tell them it helped and suggest they answer.