# Stack Exchange sites and Stack Overflow "off-topic" marked questions

Tags: discussion, rules

If I'm mistaken with the choice of Stack Exchange site why not move the question to another Stack Exchacnge site? I propose to have such functionality.

Look if that was a forum, moderators could just point to the right forum branch or thread or move the thread to the right branch by themselves. Now if a newcomer asks a question on SO and that question really should go to programmers.stackexchange.com or serverfault or superuser why not just move it?

Just to have a damn button "move to another SE site". But no, the questions are just closed.

There we a lot of "off-topic" questions and in the past. And they are visible in google results pretty often. When people see this they think it is normal to ask such a questions as they were answered. They keep asking on SO instead of the right SE site. And they keep being closed as "off-topic".

This annoys newcomers you know. And thats how sites grow. Ok SO is big already and primary source to ask a question if you are a programmer. But I see SO stagnating now.

Because of these too strict rules and lack of sensible interfaces too apply Sensible rules with "topicness".

Comment: You know, there is question migration. Though often there *is* no appropriate SE site. Or the question does not fit their guidelines.

Comment: See also ["Why not move off-topic questions instead of closing?"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254244/why-not-move-off-topic-questions-instead-of-closing)

Comment: By what measure are you seeing Stack Overflow "stagnating"? https://www.quantcast.com/stackoverflow.com

Comment: Migrate to \dev\null

Comment: @BradLarson From http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/stagnation: "Stagnation: the state or condition of stagnating, or having stopped, as by ceasing to run or flow"
What I see is a major decrease of growth. That I see as first signs of stagnation. From the link you proposed uniques:
2010 - 6 350k ;

2011 - 11 306k (+78%);

2012 - 18 802k (+66%);

2013 - 31 515k (+67%);

2014 - 38 290k (+21%);

2015 - 40 205k (+5%);

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We don't just automatically migrate off-topic questions because we expect users to go search on the correct site to see if their question is already answered before reposting it. If we just move questions without checking first, we're making more work for other people.

> This annoys newcomers you know. And thats how sites grow. Ok SO is big already and primary source to ask a question if you are a programmer. But I see SO stagnating now.

The point of Stack Exchange isn't just to grow the number of users asking questions, it is to grow the number of useful answers to questions. Having people ask a bunch of duplicate questions doesn't really serve that goal.

Comment: You know... Maybe you are right  and its just different attitude to asking questions. When you ask a question you expect others to be interested in the answer too. But in fact you got minused because you are not in right place. And people just say what is wrong without pointing where too go. This feels kind of bureaucratic for me but maybe its fine and how it should be.

Answer (score 3):

A good deal of the questions that are closed as off-topic are not of the quality necessary to make good question on the sites that would cover the topic raised by the question. The fact of the matter is that the *vast majority* of the regulars on site X are ill-equipped to judge whether a question that is off-topic for site X would be well received on sites A, B or C.

So having a "damn button" would just allow people who don't really know whether the question suited for another site to propose it only to have someone who does know (probably a moderator) turn down the request. It would be a lot of busy work for nothing.

It is already possible to suggest another site when flagging for closure or voting to close, this much is enough. The possible choices have been carefully selected to minimize bad suggestions. (Though I would not be surprised of moderators revealed that most suggestions are still bad.)